# Typescript to use Javascript object

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript

I'm developing through Node.
I have the following object in a Javascript file

```
function Person{
  this.name = 'Peter',
  this.lastname = 'Cesar',
  this.age = 23
}
```

I want to instanciate this object in my Typescript code:

```
let peter: any = new Person();
```

But I'm getting "Cannot find name'Person' " it's normal because I need to define the signature for the function before. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first I think your vanilla javascript syntax is wrong, should be

```
function Person() {
  this.name = 'Peter';
  this.lastname = 'Cesar';
  this.age = 23;
}
```

Then in typescript you can do

```
declare var Person: any;
let peter: any = new Person;
let john: any = new Person;
```

Ensure the external js is included then you can have multiple objects of Person

Comment: Nice job thats what I was looking for, I'm just wondering, why 
declare function Person(): void;

let peter: any = new Person()

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a mix of @TomKunzemann and @GauravSrivastava's answers:  You should `declare` it as a `class`.

With `declare` you are just telling the compiler about the shape and behavior of the type without implementing it, so it relies on an ambient `Person` function being included with your JavaScript.

And with `class`, you are telling TypeScript that it's the sort of thing that you instantiate with `new`.

Finally, you probably don't want to define `peter` be of type `any`, or TypeScript will not type check it afterwards.  If you just leave off the `: any`, TypeScript will infer `peter` to be of type `Person` and it will perform the desired type checks, such as detecting typos (e.g., `lastName` instead of `lastname`):

```
declare class Person {
  name: string;
  lastname: string;
  age: number;
}

let peter = new Person(); // okay
console.log(peter.name); // okay

// note the typo below
console.log(peter.lastName); // error!
// "Property 'lastName' does not exist on type 'Person'. Did you mean 'lastname'"?
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of **Person function**:

```
export class Person {
  name:string = 'Peter';
  lastname:string = 'Cesar';
  age:number = 23
}
```

Comment: I want to use it as external JS , if I do this it means its already part of the code. what I need to do in my opinion is to define the signature of the function, or typings

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think what you need to do is to "declare" the function.

```
declare function Person(): void;
```

You can read about "declare" in the official documentation.